# How can I use Youtube Analytics API without OAuth?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to extract youtube channel analytics. Is it possible to extract information like subscriber count over a period of time, number of views over a period of time, region based subscription and so on?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/):

> All YouTube Analytics and YouTube Reporting API requests must be
>   authorized by the channel or content owner that owns the requested
>   data.

And the only authentication method mentioned in the docs are the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorizing access to private user data.